# The solution of $\Delta u=u^3$ with zero boundary values is identically zero

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

**My question:**

[image]

**My attempt:**

I tried to use the Representation using Green's formula: [image]
Since $u=0$ on the boundary and $f(x)=x^3$, then the formula becomes:

$$u(x)=\int_\Omega y^3G(x,y)dy \quad (x\in\Omega)$$

Then I got stuck, how to proceed to get $u=0$?

Can anyone give me some clues or answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Green's idenitity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547150/greens-first-and-second-identities) says that 
$$\int_{\Omega}u\Delta u+\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2=\int_{\partial\Omega} u(\nabla u\cdot n).$$
Since $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ by assumption, the right hand side is zero. On the other hand, $\Delta u=u^3$ in $\Omega$ by assumption, the left hand side is equal to 
$$\int_{\Omega}u^4+\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2.$$
Combining all these, we have 
$$\int_{\Omega}u^4+\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2=0$$
which implies that $u\equiv 0$.

Comment: My professor says this is not right because divergence theorem may not hold in $\Omega$