# Proof of generalization of Divergence theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I looked around the Web for a proof of what I have heard called "the Divergence theorem". However, it seems this name implies three-dimensionality, as all I could find was a series of proofs [like this](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~rchen/Advanced%20Calculus/divergence%20theorem.pdf) which work in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What I would like a proof of is:

**Divergence Theorem**

If $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded $\mathcal{C}^1$ domain and $\underline w\in\mathbb{C}^1(\overline\Omega)$ is a field, then:

$$\int\limits_\Omega\operatorname{div}\underline wdV=\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}\underline w\cdot\nu d\sigma,$$

$\nu$ being the outward unit normal and $d\sigma$ the surface measure.

While we are at it, it would be nice to have an idea of where this surface measure comes from. I have been told a $\mathcal{C}^k$ hypersurface is a hypersurface locally described as the locus of zeros of a function $F\in\mathcal{C}^k(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ with everywhere nonzero gradient, and that thus locally a derivative of $F$, say the $j$th, is always nonzero so by the implicit function theorem we can represent $x_j=\phi(x_1,\dotsc,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},\dotsc,x_n)$ and have the hypersurface as the locus where $x_j=\phi(\text{the other coordinates})$, and that with that the surface measure is $\sqrt{1+|\nabla\phi(x)|^2}dx_1\dotsc dx_{n-1}$. How is this expression found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I decided to look for a reference, and I found:

[image]

On pp. 123-132, the book proves integration by parts and deduces the Divergence theorem from it. Since it looks very similar to the proof I saw for the 2- and 3-dimensional case in Analysis two (the only difference is having more variables and hence more $dx$'s and more derivatives), I think I will sooner or later adapt that proof into one written over here to have it available.

**Update**

One way to deduce it from other results is using Stokes' theorem (the one with the exterior derivatives, not the one with the integral of the curl). Said theorem states:

$$\int_U\mathrm{d}\omega=\int_{\partial U}\omega.$$

Let us find a form such that:

$$\mathrm{d}\omega=\nabla\cdot F\mathrm{d}V_{n+1},$$

where $F$ is a field on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\mathrm{d}V_{n+1}$ is the canonical volume form on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. It is easily seen that this gives:

$$\omega=\sum_i(-1)^{i-1}F_i\ast(\mathrm{d}x_i),$$

where $\ast(\mathrm{d}x_i)$ is $\mathrm{d}V$ with $\mathrm{d}x_i$ removed. So the LHS is easy. The RHS, on the other hand, needs a pullback via a chart. The hypersurface is $\mathcal{C}^k$, so we have a $\mathcal{C}^k$ chart $G(x)=(x,\phi(x))$. I didn't calculate the pullback in general, but I did a calculation for $n+1=3$. In that case, we have:

$$\omega=F_1\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge\mathrm{d}x_3-F_2\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_3+F_3\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_3.$$

Before pulling back $\omega$, we pull back $\mathrm{d}x_i$. Since the first two coordinates of $\mathrm{d}G$ are the identity, $\mathrm{d}x_1$ and $\mathrm{d}x_2$ are pulled back to "themselves". Instead, $\mathrm{d}x_3$ is pulled back to $\mathrm{d}\phi$. Now we use the linearity and distributivity over wedges of the pullback:

\begin{align*}
G^\ast\omega={}&F_1G^\ast(\mathrm{d}x_2)\wedge G^\ast(\mathrm{d}x_3)-F_2G^\ast(\mathrm{d}x_1)\wedge G^\ast(\mathrm{d}x_3)+F_3G^\ast(\mathrm{d}x_1)\wedge G^\ast(\mathrm{d}x_2)={} \\
{}={}&F_1\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi-F_2\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi+F_3\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2={} \\
{}={}&F_1\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge(\partial_1\phi\mathrm{d}x_1+\partial_2\phi\mathrm{d}x_2)-F_2\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge(\partial_1\mathrm{d}x_1+\partial_2\mathrm{d}x_2)+F_3\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2={} \\
{}\underset{\mathrm{d}V':=\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2}{=}{}&(-F_1\partial_1\phi-F_2\partial_2\phi+F_3)\mathrm{d}V'={} \\
{}={}&(-\nabla\phi,1)\cdot F\mathrm{d}V'.
\end{align*}

So trusting this calculation generalizes to the same formula in arbitrary dimensions, we get exactly the theorem desired.

While we are at it, let us see where the surface measure come from. The orientation on the boundary $\partial U$ is the interior product of the canonical volume form $\mathrm{d}V=\bigwedge_1^{n+1}\mathrm{d}x_i$ and the normal field $\nu=(-\nabla\phi,1)$. Let us compute this:

$$\iota_\nu\mathrm{d}V=\sum(-1)^{i-1}N_i\mathrm{d}V_{\widehat{\mathrm{d}x_i}}=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i\partial_i\phi\mathrm{d}V_{\widehat{\mathrm{d}x_i}}+(-1)^n\mathrm{d}V_{\widehat{\mathrm{d}x_{n+1}}}.$$

Let us, once again, set $n=2$. Then:

$$\iota_\nu\mathrm{d}V=-\partial_1\phi\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge\mathrm{d}x_3+\partial_2\phi\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_3+\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2.$$

Pull it back:

\begin{align*}
G^\ast(\iota_\nu\mathrm{d}V)={}&-\partial_1\phi\mathrm{d}x_2\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi+\partial_2\phi\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}\phi+\mathrm{d}x_1\wedge\mathrm{d}x_2={} \\
{}={}&(\partial_1\phi)^2\mathrm{d}V+(\partial_2\phi)^2\mathrm{d}V'+\mathrm{d}V'={} \\
{}={}&(\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla\phi+1)\mathrm{d}V',
\end{align*}

where $\mathrm{d}V'$ is as defined above. Oh. The square root is not present. But then again, we were supposed to normalize the normal before $\iota_\nu$-ing, so the normalizing factor makes the square root appear again. Fantastic!

Thanks for the suggestion, Omnomnomnom (is that the right number of "nom"s :)?).

Answer (score 2):

There are two generalizations that imply your result. One is that of [Green's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities), and the other is the [generalized Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#General_formulation). I would advise that you look for a proof of the first of Green's identities.

Comment: Actually, we did Green's identities in class as a corollary of this result :). Generalized Stokes theorem... let me see.

Comment: I think you can prove it as purely a consequence of integration by parts

Comment: Another corollary of it in our class treatment :). I mean in higher dimensions we deduced ibp from this result.

Comment: I mean that you could prove Green's as a consequence of one-dimensional integration by parts.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Oh. I can't quite see how. What are you thinking?

Comment: Not sure, off the top of my head. I'd have to look at a blackboard for a bit before I get any kind of direction here.  The Generalized Stokes' theorem is elegant, but there's a lot to understand before you can really make sense of it, and I think it's overkill here.

Comment: I guess so. Not to mention this result comes from a course called Higher Analysis and I'm possibly the only one in that class who knows about manifolds :). Ah wait, there is at least another one. But she knows nothing of forms on manifolds...

Comment: I mean, if you happen to know about Stokes' theorem, then you might as well use it here.  It's a long road, however, if you haven't seen exterior derivatives.

Comment: Btw [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547150/greens-first-and-second-identities) is more or less what we did in class. Actually, I never had anything about forms outside euclidean spaces in any course, and even then, I stopped at 1-forms, with 2-forms in the distance for an alternate definition of closed 1-form (alternate to the analytic one with crossed derivatives). I'm entirely self-taught on exterior derivatives and forms on manifolds and form integration besides path integration.

Comment: Looking for Green's identities online yields nothing, seen as every other link starts from the Divergence theorem to prove them and I want to use them to prove DT so it would lead to a circular argument which is no good. How could I do this with Stokes' theorem? I know that when I integrate the divergence I am integrating $\sum\partial_iF_idx^1\wedge\dotso\wedge dx^n$, which is the exterior derivative of $\sum(-1)^{i-1}F_idx^1\wedge\dotso\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dotso\wedge dx^n$, but how do i get the integral of that over $\partial\Omega$ to look like the "surface integral" of $F\cdot\nu$?

Comment: I have also figured out $\nu$ is actually $(-\nabla\phi,1)$, modulo normalization. But still…

Comment: Stokes' theorem uses the Stokes orientation, specified by the volume form $\iota_N\Omega$, where $N$ is the normal, $\iota_N$ is the interior product, and $\Omega$ is the orientation form on the ambient manifold, in this case $dx^1\wedge\dotso\wedge dx^n$. So the orientation form on $\partial\Omega$ would be $\iota_N\Omega=\sum(-1)^{i-1}N_idx_{\hat i}=\sum_1^{n-1}(-1)^i\partial_i\phi dx_{\hat i}+(-1)^{n-1}dx_{\hat n}$, where $dx_{\hat i}=dx^1\wedge\dotso\wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dotso\wedge dx^n$.

Comment: Now I must compute the pullback of my form whose $d$ is $\nabla\cdot Fdx^1\wedge\dotso\wedge dx^n$. Pullback via what, though?

Comment: OK no. I restrict that form to the manifold, then pull it back via the inverse of the chart. THe chart is the projection, and the inverse is $\underline x\mapsto(\underline x,\phi(\underline x))$.

Comment: Call the map $G$. $(G^\ast\omega)_x(v_1,\dotsc,v_{n-1})=\omega_{G(x)}(dG(v_1),\dotsc,dG(v_{n-1})$. Now $dG$ maps $(a_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1})$ into $(\sum\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial x_i}a_i,\dotsc,\sum\frac{\partial G_n}{\partial x_i}a_i)=(a_1,\dotsc,a_{n-1},\nabla\phi(\underline x)\cdot\underline a)$.

Comment: [Here is what I've calculated for this pullback](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zfuwB.jpg). Can't seem to get anything sensible out of it though…